# How can I cast a variable to generic type in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have this method

```dart
void doSomething<T>() { ... }
```

and a variable of type `T`

```dart
T someVar = ...;
```

how can I use `doSomething` method to perform an action on `someVar`, something like this?

```dart
doSomething<someVar.Type>();
```

in fact, I want to access `Type T` form variable.

---

***here is the example***

```dart
class BlocManagerProvider extends StatefulWidget {
  const BlocManagerProvider({
    @required this.child,
    @required this.blocs,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final List<Cubit<Object>> blocs;

  @override
  _BlocManagerProviderState createState() => _BlocManagerProviderState();
}

class _BlocManagerProviderState extends State<BlocManagerProvider> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => widget.child;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (final Cubit<Object> bloc in widget.blocs) {
        BlocManager.instance.dispose<type>();
    }

    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

```dart
  Future<void> dispose<T extends Cubit<Object>>() async {
    final String objectKey = _getKey<T>(key);

    if (_repository.containsKey(objectKey)) {
      await _repository[objectKey].close();
      _repository.remove(objectKey);

      await removeListener<T>(key);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You cannot supply an expression as the type for a generic.  If you already know that `someVar` is of type `T`, why can't you explicitly invoke `doSomething<T>()`?  What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: @jamesdlin because `doSomething` methods work with `type` and types may vary.

Comment: Please provide a full example of what you're trying to accomplish.  You said that you know `someVar` is of type `T`, so you would be able to specify `T` as a type parameter for `doSomething`.

Comment: @jamesdlin here you are...

Comment: Generics are meant to be used with statically-known types.  They are effectively compile-time syntactic sugar.  If you need to iterate over a list of objects and perform operations on them based on their *dynamic* (runtime) type, then you will need to use a *dynamic* mechanism for dispatch (e.g. polymorphism).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart does not provide a way to go from an object of type `X` to a type variable bound to `X`. There are good technical reasons for not allowing that (it allows the web compilers to know at compile-time which types can ever be bound to a type variable, which allows it to reduce the compiled code).

The `dispose` method is treating the type argument as its only argument and acting on the value of that type argument.
It makes me think you're trying to do something that the language is not designed for.

You're passing in a type argument, and then the code inspects that type of argument and behaves differently depending on the value. That's not what's usually meant by being "generic" - to act the in the *same* (generic) way *independently* of the types, so the only real effect of passing a type is to make the return type match the argument type.
(That's why Java can erase type arguments at run-time).

So, if you need to know a type for some object, either that object must provide it for you, or you have to store it from earlier (perhaps when the object was created).

So, if you really need to access the *type argument* that the cubit is implementing `Cubit<X>` of, the `Cubit` class needs to make it available to you. That will usually be with a method with a callback (like a visitor), something like:

```dart
abstract class Cubit<T> ... {
  ...
  R visit<R>(R Function<C extends Cubit<T>, T>(C value) action);
}

class SomeCubit<T> extends Cubit<T> { 
  ...
  R visit<R>(R Function<C extends Cubit<T>, T>(C value) action) => 
      action<SomeCubit<T>, T>(this);
}
```

If something like that's available, then you can do what you want as:

```dart
bloc.visit(<C extends Cubit<T>, T>(_) => BlocManager.instance.dispose<C>());
```

If something like that is *not* available, then you are in trouble.

You can detect a number of *known* types, with a bunch of `if` statements, but that's unlikely to be sufficient.

That means you need to remember the type from earlier, but since it looks like you just get a `List<Cubit<Object>>` that has already been created, that doesn't seem practical either.

If the `BlocManager` is your own class, consider changing it to use `Type` objects instead of type arguments (which is contrary to everything I usually say you should do), because then you can call `..dispose(bloc.runtimeType)`. I'd prefer to avoid that, but if other constraints make what you do impossible, then it might be the lesser evil.